# Multiple entries with same key: FirebaseInstanceId

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

Getting strange error after updating Android Studio to 3.5.

The error comes only for release apk. debug apk generates well.

```
Multiple entries with same key: Method com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza Proto LLL com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task java.lang.String java.lang.String=Encoded method Method com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza Proto LLL com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task java.lang.String java.lang.String and Method com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza Proto LLL com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task java.lang.String java.lang.String=Encoded method Method com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza Proto LLL com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task java.lang.String java.lang.String
```

Comment: Please do not use 'android studio' tag unless the issue is specifically linked to the IDE itself, and not Android in general or any of its libraries.

Comment: @ArthurAttout It's working in other versions excluding 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to proguard files :

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId { zza(...); }
```

see [details here.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132575649#comment8)

Comment: Thanks.  It worked. I already went through that link. but couldn't find it. :-)